# No test is available error while running coded UI test on VSTS deployment group

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, vstest, vstest.console.exe, vstest.console

We have configured release definition to run coded UI tests on VSTS deployment group.

Unable to launch the tests, error details:

Windows Error Reporting DontShowUI not set, if the windows error dialog pops-up in the middle of UI test execution than the test will hang

### [debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=warning;]Windows Error Reporting DontShowUI not set, if the windows error dialog pops-up in the middle of UI test execution than the test will hang.

No test is available in c:\test\WorkFlow.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

How do we resolve this issue as the tests can be initiated manually using vstest.console.exe

Comment: Which agent do you use? Hosted agent or private agent?

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT We are using an Azure VM which is configured to be part of a deployment group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by reconfiguring the agent in interactive mode and not as a service.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure the agent machine has the VS 2017 Enterprise installed, as other versions don't support the Coded UI Testing, please see [Compare Visual Studio 2017 IDEs -Testing Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/) for details.

Besides, please check which version of `VSTest platform` nuget package do you use. Coded UI and UWP tests not support with previous VSTest platform nuget packages. Just try using the [latest version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TestPlatform/15.9.0-preview-20180816-01), then try it again. Refer to this thread for details: https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/1353

Other similar issues for your reference:

- [Cannot load test assembly using Nuget VsTest Platform and VS Test
  runner](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/6966)
- [Windows Error Reporting DontShowUI](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/18700da8-1861-4992-836e-da8b632f65c5/windows-error-reporting-dontshowui?forum=vsunittest)